React Native Expo : Google Signin Notwork in debug mode
eact native expo app, in this npx expo run:android debug mode Google signin not work.
Possible unhandled promise rejection (id:0): error: Developer_Error
when make apk file using eas build -p android --profile preview its working well
how to fix this
I'm trying to run login with google button in react native expo debug app.
